# Use "some" variable within a csv file data set in a function to return any variable within data set

Tags: r, function, sorting, variables, concatenation

I am trying to create a function where I can return the top x players for a particular variable within my data set. For example, the data consists of MLB Players with all kinds of statistics. In my function, I want to be able to choose whichever variable, for example `CHits` (Career Hits) and print the top 3 or 5 or 10. With that **same** function, I want to print the top players of CRBIs (Career RBIs).

Here is my current code.

```
My_Top_CHits <- function(x) 
  {y <- Hitters[order(-Hitters$CHits),]
  top <- y[1:x,]cat("The Top", x, "MLB Players in 1986 based on Career Hits:")
  return(top)}

My_Top_CHits(3)

My_Top_CHits(4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add an input parameter for column stat name and use `head` for top N rows:

```
My_Top_Stats <- function(x, col_stat) {

  y <- Hitters[order(-Hitters[[col_stat]]),]    
  top <- head(y, x)

  cat("The Top", x, "MLB Players in 1986 based on ", col_stat, " is:")
  return(top)
}

My_Top_Stats(3, "CHits")

My_Top_Stats(4, "CRBIs")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work:

```
> My_Top_CHits <- function(df, variable, n) {
+   df %>%
+     arrange(desc(!!as.symbol(variable))) %>%
+     slice(1:n)
+ }
> 
> dat <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3),
+                   B = c(10,11,12))
> My_Top_CHits(dat, "A", 2)
  A  B
1 3 12
2 2 11
```